# What will be the latex code for this

Tags: math-mode

Specifically I want the code for this diagram. I am very new to latex…Please help[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: I would recommend the suggestions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693) especially Grätzer's *More Math into LaTeX*.  The displayed object can be easily made with an `array` environment.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest `tikz-cd` for this diagram. Use arrow type `-` for the lines, and `<->` for the bijection.

[image]

The package `amsmath` (probably already in your document) is needed for `\DeclareMathOperator`, to get proper spacing and shape of `Gal`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}

\begin{document}

Let $K/F$ be a Galois extension and set $G=\Gal(K/F)$. Denote by $E$ the subfields of $K$ containing $F$ and $H$ the subgroups of $G$. Then there is a bijection:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
K\arrow[d, -] & 1\arrow[d, -]\\
E\arrow[d, -]\arrow[r, <->] & H\arrow[d, -]\\
F & G
\end{tikzcd}
\]
given by the correspondence

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is given by `tikz-cd` package like this example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep =-1.2]
K                    &                 & 1                    \\
E \arrow[u, no head] & \leftrightarrow & H \arrow[u, no head] \\
F \arrow[u, no head] &                 & G \arrow[u, no head]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without “fancy” packages and avoiding the inconsistency appearing in the image,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}

\begin{document}

Let $K/F$ be a Galois extension and set $G=\Gal(K/F)$. 
Denote by $E$ the subfields of $K$ containing $F$ and $H$ 
the subgroups of $G$. Then there is a bijection
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
K && 1 \\
\Bigl| && \Bigl| \\ \noalign{\vspace{2pt}}
E & \leftrightarrow & H \\
\Bigl| && \Bigl| \\ \noalign{\vspace{2pt}}
F && G 
\end{array}
\]
given by the correspondence
\[
\begin{aligned}
E &\rightarrow \{\text{elements of $G$ fixing $E$}\} \\
\{\text{the fixed field of $H$}\} &\mspace{-1mu}\leftarrow H
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note the `\mspace{-1mu}` that's needed to avoid the impression that the arrows are not aligned. Note also the usage of math mode inside `\text` to have proper italic letters, not the wrong upright ones in the image.

However, since you will be probably needing other diagrams, maybe more complex than the one above, learning the basics of `tikz-cd` is much better.

[image]